# Create a matrix ( mx n) with gaussian random distribution

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, gaussian

How to create a Matlab matrix (m x n) with random Gaussian distribution of numbers 0 and 1, when the number of 1's is a% and number of 0 is (100-a)%?

for example in one dimension that is "00000010001001011010111011101111111111111110110101001010010001000000" but I want 2D matrix such that there is a lot of "1" in the center of the matrix and there is a lot of "0" in the border of the matrix (change 1 to 0 with Gaussian distribution from center to border).

The definition of Gaussian matrix can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GaussianMatrix.html)

Comment: How is the matrix a Gaussian distribution if the matrix only consists of 0s and 1s? That doesn't make any sense.  Do you want a Gaussian matrix, or do you want a matrix that consists of 0s and 1s populated according to the percentages you have outlined above?  It can only be one or the other.

Comment: I suppose that for a sufficiently large matrix, the density of 1s within "circles" in the matrix could be made to be approximately Gaussian. But the overall density would hardly meet a (`a`,`1-a`) type constraint on top of that.

Comment: Why don't you just define a circle of all `1` where the total area is a%, and the remaining elements are `0` which has a total area of (100-a)%? What you just defined is not a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @rayryeng , you suppose with mean a and with variance b

Comment: What you defined as your problem description isn't Gaussian at all, and so there is no need for mean or variance. Given a matrix of size m x n, and given an area of a%, first determine what radius you need, then generate a circle in the centre of the m x n matrix of all 1s.  The rest of the elements you set to 0.

Comment: @rayryeng,Please look at the nkjt's answer

Comment: That only answers the first question. The desired probability part is still unanswered... But that's totally fine. We're going to leave that to you as you obviously haven't tried anything up to this point. @nkjt great answer!

Comment: @rayryeng,Not that you can set a% "1" in the output matrix by change sigma in the fspecial function so nkjt hase answered perfect.By the way I have tried enough but I could not create this matrix exact. Nkjt could answer correct in one comment and without any problem.However thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems you're wanting the probability of having a `1` at any point to be governed by some sort of gaussian function.

1) Create a 2D gaussian function (e.g. using `fspecial`), scaled between 0 and 1.

2) Create a 2D random matrix of the same size (using `rand`).

3) Create an output matrix containing zeros and set it to one wherever the random value is lower than the gaussian.

```
myoutput(r<g) = 1;
```

[image]

Finding a gaussian which gives you your desired overall probability is another matter.